# visual studio cordova change ios build settings

Tags: ios, swift, visual-studio-cordova

I'm trying to use swift with visual studio Cordova , the problem is when try to change build settings by putting a new setting in 
res/native/iOS/Cordova/build.xcconfig
it doesn't work, nothing change.

this is my build.xcconfig file

> SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER =
>   $(PROJECT_NAME)/Plugins/MyAllPlugins/Bridging-Header.h
>
> LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks
>
> CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Developer
>   CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*] = iPhone Developer

I also try to put my new settings in the three files build.xcconfig , build-debug.xcconfig and build-release.xcconfig , but also nothing change

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having this problem due to filename casing. Try putting you config files into /res/native/ios/*cordova*  and **not** into /res/native/iOS/*Cordova*.